# Federal income tax calculator for procrastinators

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic

<strike>Today is [Tax Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_Day)!</strike>

Oops.

Well, [today is tax day if you are a resident of Maine or Massachusetts](https://www.irs.com/articles/tax-deadline-alert-2015-tax-returns-are-due-april-18-2016).

So you're probably still completing your return and need a calculator for when you get to [Line 44](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040.pdf).

Given an input of taxable income (US$, accurate to 2 decimal places) and a string representing filing status, output the amount of tax (also US$ to 2 decimal places).

Filing status will be one of `S`, `MFJ`, `QW`, `MFS`, or `HH` for Single, Married Filing Jointly, Qualified Widow(er), Married Filing Separately or Head of Household, respectively.

- Tax will be calculated according to the official tables in [IRS Revenue Procedure 2014-61, section .01 Tax Rate Tables, Tables 1-4](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-drop/rp-14-61.pdf).  I have added these tables at the bottom of the question.
- You may choose whatever rounding method you like, as long as the result is accurate to 2 decimal places.

#### Example Inputs:

```
0.00 S
10000.00 MFJ
100000.00 MFS
1000000.00 QW
```

#### Example Outputs corresponding to above inputs:

```
0.00
1000.00
21525.75
341915.90
```

---

## Summary of tax tables.

#### Married Filing Jointly and Qualified Widow(er)

> `Income Interval       Tax
>   [     $0,  $18450]                 10%
>   ( $18450,  $74900]      $1845    + 15%   of the excess over  $18450
>   ( $74900, $151200]     $10312.50 + 25%   of the excess over  $74900
>   ($151200, $230450]     $29387.50 + 28%   of the excess over $151200
>   ($230450, $411500]     $51577.50 + 33%   of the excess over $230450
>   ($411500, $464850]    $111324    + 35%   of the excess over $411500
>   ($464850,      $∞]    $129996.50 + 39.6% of the excess over $464850`

#### Head of Household

> `Income Interval       Tax
>   [     $0,  $13150]                 10%
>   ( $13150,  $50200]      $1315    + 15%   of the excess over  $13150
>   ( $50200, $129600]      $6872.50 + 25%   of the excess over  $50200
>   ($129600, $209850]     $26722.50 + 28%   of the excess over $129600
>   ($209850, $411500]     $49192.50 + 33%   of the excess over $209850
>   ($411500, $439000]    $115737    + 35%   of the excess over $411500
>   ($439000,      $∞]    $125362    + 39.6% of the excess over $439000`

#### Single

> `Income Interval       Tax
>   [     $0,   $9225]                 10%
>   (  $9225,  $37450]       $922.50 + 15%   of the excess over   $9225
>   ( $37450,  $90750]      $5156.25 + 25%   of the excess over  $37450
>   ( $90750, $189300]     $18481.25 + 28%   of the excess over  $90750
>   ($189300, $411500]     $46075.25 + 33%   of the excess over $189300
>   ($411500, $413200]    $119401.25 + 35%   of the excess over $411500
>   ($413200,      $∞]    $119996.25 + 39.6% of the excess over $413200`

#### Married Filing Separately

> `Income Interval       Tax
>   [     $0,   $9225]                 10%
>   (  $9225,  $37450]       $922.50 + 15%   of the excess over   $9225
>   ( $37450,  $75600]      $5156.25 + 25%   of the excess over  $37450
>   ( $75600, $115225]     $14693.75 + 28%   of the excess over  $75600
>   ($115225, $205750]     $25788.75 + 33%   of the excess over $115225
>   ($205750, $232425]     $55662    + 35%   of the excess over $205750
>   ($232425,      $∞]     $64998.25 + 39.6% of the excess over $232425`

Comment: I'd like to see "golf the entire functionality of TurboTax"

Comment: @qwr I don't think golfing works well with the whole "fix it every year" that tax code has to be

Comment: @CAD97 Nonsense, even this problem is year dependent!

Answer (score 5):

### Python 3, <s>427</s> <s>382</s> <s>317</s> <s>309</s> <s>308</s> 275 bytes

*-45 bytes by figuring ternary expression out (wow that's a long line); thanks [Maltysen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31343/)*

*-65 bytes, now with iteration for DRYer code!*

*-8 bytes by in-lining tuple variables; thanks [Majora](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53146)*

*-1 byte by using a dict rather than ternary chain; thanks again [Maltysen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31343/)*

*-33 bytes by reusing `MFS` step as half of `MFJ`/`QW` and calculating tax an order of magnitude larger; thanks [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602)*

```python
def f(i,s):
 t=i;k={'MFS':(9225,28225,38150,39625,90525,26675),'S':(9225,28225,53300,98550,222200,1700),'HH':(13150,37050,79400,80250,201650,27500)}
 for x in range(6):
  i-=k[s][x]if s in k else k['MFS'][x]*2
  if i>0:t+=(.5,1,.3,.5,.2,.46)[x]*i
 return'{:.2f}'.format(t*.1)
```

If I had been thinking I would have made the function signature `t(a,x)`, but I guess I'll stick with `f`unction(`i`ncome, `s`tatus).

<strike>When code is barely undertstood by the writer, is that when you win at golf?</strike>

Comment: you can save by changing the ifs into a series of ternaries and having only one `a,b,c,d,e,f=`

Comment: @Maltysen And now since I figured out how to iterate to save repetition of taxation, I only have to assign the tuple :)

Comment: You can shave off 10 bytes by replacing `c` and `r` with the literal tuple, because they are only used once. (tested, working; even works with the long `c` line)

Comment: you can prolly save more with either dicts or indexing and slicing.

Comment: @Majora I had to put parenthesis around the in-lined c to make it index properly. Is this a python version issue? (I'm running `3.5.1`.)

Comment: @Maltysen The problem with a dictionary is that both `MJF` and `QW` have to map to the same tuple (here the last else). I will try it, though. I don't really see where indexing and slicing could help any more at this point.

Comment: @CAD97 No, that's normal, now that I think about it... Other wise it would be `else(18450,56450,76300,79250,181050,53350)[x]`, which would mean `...[x]` if the else clause was reached.

Comment: @Maltysen Wow, using a dict is actually shorter by one character. And (slightly) more readable.

Comment: @CAD97 You can assign the repeated tuple to a variable and reference it twice from the dict (Not sure how many chars it would save you). If you did this, you could also inline the dict.

Comment: @Majora320 +3 bytes from current, if my count is correct.

Comment: *"When code is barely undertstood by the writer, is that when you win at golf"*.  Almost.  The next step is to port your code to [pyth](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/) :)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Or Seriously/Actually. Deer god, that would be terrifying. I might be working on that now.

Comment: I think you can save 6 bytes using `t=i`, `(.5,1,.3,.5,.2,.46)` and `format(t*.1)`.

Comment: Does `i-=(k[s][x]if s in k else k['MFS'][x]*2)` work?

Comment: You can shave off a few bytes by replacing the indentation of 2 spaces with a single tab character on the lines `i-=...` and `if i>0...` if you want to swap to Python 2. You can also save a byte (newline) by putting the declaration of `k` and `t` on the same line, separated by a `;` like so: `k={...};t=.1*i`

Comment: @Neil, yeah, it works. Nicely spotted!

Comment: Would it save some bytes to change the second indentation to tab?

Comment: @KennyLau It would if I switched to Python 2 but seeing as it's only a trivial 2-byte difference and I don't have the Py2 runtime on my computer I'm not going to bother

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 223 bytes

```
(i,s)=>(({MFS:a=[x=9225,y=28225,38150,39625,90525,26675],S:[x,y,53300,98550,222200,1700],HH:[13150,37050,79400,80250,201650,27500]}[s]||a.map(b=>b*2)).reduce((t,b,j)=>t+((i-=b)>0&&i*[.5,1,.3,.5,.2,.46][j]),i)*.1).toFixed(2)
```

Basically a port of CAD97's Python answer, but I saved 4 bytes by multiplying the tax by 10 during the calculation and 11 bytes by reducing the duplication in the tax bands.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Oops I don't develop on the machine on which I have PPCG open so sometimes I typo when copying the code across. (The beauty of Code Golf is that I want to copy as little code as possible!)

Comment: Good.  Works for me now in both firefox and chrome.