# Calculate the Trump Tax

Tags: code-golf, number

If elected president, Donald Trump plans to implement a system of four income tax brackets (full details can be found on his website [here](https://www.donaldjtrump.com/positions/tax-reform)). Your job is to take two inputs, annual income and filing status (single, married, or head of household), and output the income tax that must be paid.

## Income Tax Brackets

[image: The Trump Tax]

(We are only interested in the income tax rate; you can ignore the long-term capital gain rate).

Note that income taxes are computed using *marginal rates* — that is, you only pay the bracket rate for the portion that exceeds the bracket's minimum amount.

For example, a single filer making $45,000 a year would pay 0% on the first $25,000, and 10% on the $20,000 after that, for a total of $2,000 in taxes.

A married couple filing jointly for $500,000 would count 25% only on the amount exceeding $300,000, and add $45,000 to that to account for the income earned in lower brackets (which is 10% of $50,000 plus 20% of $200,000).

## Input/Output

Input/Output is flexible. You can take input as command-line arguments or prompt for inputs, as well as either return or output/display the result. The inputs and output must be numbers, but you are free to determine what the second number would be (for example, 0 = single, 1 = married, 2 = head of household). Just don't be ridiculous - **Single digit numbers only**.

Also, functionality for decimal inputs (i.e. including cents) is undefined, so you only have to worry about integer inputs. For your output, you may either output a decimal value or round it to the nearest whole number.

## Test Cases

Although the second number's range can be flexible as stated above, these test cases assume that 0 = single, 1 = married, and 2 = head of household:

```
25000  0 --> 0
37501  2 --> 0.1 or 0
51346  1 --> 134.6 or 135
75000  0 --> 7500
75000  1 --> 2500
123456 2 --> 13441.2 or 13441
424242 0 --> 91060.5 or 91061
```

Comment: [Closely related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/78078/20469)

Comment: You are advised to wait for at least a day, preferably two days, before posting your question.

Comment: How much information can I encode in the second input?

Comment: @KennyLau By "don't be ridiculous", how about single digit numbers only...

Comment: Then say that explicitly.

Comment: Why not just say "you may not encode program information in the input"?

Comment: Because that would be too broad. Even `0`, `1`, `2` can be considered "program information"

Comment: Does the tax amount really jump up when you cross a boundary? I thought that tax brackets  work that you pay 0% for the first $25000 if single, then 10% for the portion between 25000 and 50000, and so on.

Comment: @xnor This is what I thought too. Timtech's testing inputs are wrong.

Comment: The link in the question is dead. [Here is the archive entry](https://web.archive.org/web/20160101193319/https://www.donaldjtrump.com/positions/tax-reform)

Answer (score 7):

## Pyth, 32 bytes

```
*c@_j270588 6shS,6ca0tQ*12500E20
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=*c%40_j270588+6shS%2C6ca0tQ*12500E20&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=25000%0A2%0A37501%0A3%0A51346%0A4%0A75000%0A2%0A75000%0A4%0A123456%0A3%0A424242%0A2&debug=0&input_size=2)

- 2 = single
- 4 = married
- 3 = head of household

### Some ridiculous encodings:

#### Previous 6-byte:

```
JQ.vCE
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JQ.vCE&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A74892585093965377905208487730659359537614936740881725652453863997600444976%0A%0A25000%0A74892585093965377905208487730659359537614936740881725652453863997600444976%0A%0A37501%0A74892585093965377905208487730659359537614936740881725652526490039149933104%0A%0A51346%0A74892585093965377905208487730659359537614936740881725652668629404830675504%0A%0A75000%0A74892585093965377905208487730659359537614936740881725652453863997600444976%0A%0A75000%0A74892585093965377905208487730659359537614936740881725652668629404830675504%0A%0A123456%0A74892585093965377905208487730659359537614936740881725652526490039149933104%0A%0A424242%0A74892585093965377905208487730659359537614936740881725652453863997600444976%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)

- 74892585093965377905208487730659359537614936740881725652453863997600444976 = single
- 74892585093965377905208487730659359537614936740881725652668629404830675504 = married
- 74892585093965377905208487730659359537614936740881725652526490039149933104 = head of household

Encodes the whole program into the second number.

#### Previous 24-byte:

```
JjE^T6*c@tJhS,7shctQhJ20
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JjE%5ET6*c%40tJhS%2C7shctQhJ20&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A25000000000000000000002000004000004000004000004000005%0A%0A25000%0A25000000000000000000002000004000004000004000004000005%0A%0A37501%0A37500000000000000000002000004000004000004000004000005%0A%0A51346%0A50000000000000000000002000004000004000004000004000005%0A%0A75000%0A25000000000000000000002000004000004000004000004000005%0A%0A75000%0A50000000000000000000002000004000004000004000004000005%0A%0A123456%0A37500000000000000000002000004000004000004000004000005%0A%0A424242%0A25000000000000000000002000004000004000004000004000005%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)

- 25000000000000000000002000004000004000004000004000005 = single
- 50000000000000000000002000004000004000004000004000005 = married
- 37500000000000000000002000004000004000004000004000005 = head of household

#### Previous 26-byte:

```
*c@_j270588 6shS,6ca0tQE20
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=*c%40_j270588+6shS%2C6ca0tQE20&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=25000%0A25000%0A%0A37501%0A37500%0A%0A51346%0A50000%0A%0A75000%0A25000%0A%0A75000%0A50000%0A%0A123456%0A37500%0A%0A424242%0A25000%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)

- 25000 = single
- 50000 = married
- 37500 = head of household

Comment: OP has updated to specify "single digit numbers only"

Answer (score 5):

## TI-Basic, <strike>34</strike> 32 bytes

Variable `F` is filing status where 2 = single, 3 = head of household, and 4 = married. Also, E is the scientific E.

```
Prompt I,F:4I/F>E5{.5,1,3:.1Isum(Ans{1,1,.5
```

Explanation:

```
Prompt I,F          get input into I and F
4I/F               converts the income so it fits the married tax bracket
    >E5{.5,1,3     gives a list like {0 0 0}, {1 0 0}, {1 1 0}, or {1 1 1} based on bracket
   sum(Ans{1,1,.5  Multiplies previous list by {1 1 .5} and sums it
.1I                Previous number is 0 1 2 or 2.5, so multiply by .1 and then by income
```

Comment: I'm not horribly familiar with TI-Basic, but would newlines instead of colons save bytes, or just displayable characters?

Comment: Which TI-Basic? 83? 84? Nspire?

Comment: what is the scientific `E`?

Comment: @LeifWillerts http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/e-ten

Comment: duh, of course!

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 52 bytes

```
(i,m,g=b=>i>b&&(i-=b)/10)=>g(m=15e4/m)+g(m)+g(m*4)/2
```

Key:

```
6 = Single
3 = Married
4 = Head
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 24 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ï¥Ωü+àqGZvwJ╫BMwbë↕)bÿ╠»
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8b9dea812b8571475a76774ad7424d77628912296298ccaf&i=2,+25000%0A3,+37501%0A4,+51346%0A2,+75000%0A4,+75000%0A3,+123456%0A2,+424242%0A&a=1&m=2)

\begin{align}\text{Single}&\mapsto 2\\
\text{Married}&\mapsto4\\
\text{Head of Household}&\mapsto3
\end{align}

Outputs a fraction.